# Adafruit IO + Esp-Now

Tags: wifi, esp32, adafruit

So i am using adafruit io and esp-now on an esp32 to recieve voice commands from the internet and sensor values from another esp32. Independently, they both work quite fast but together the esp-now recieving speed slows down greatly with more packets lost. Any reason for that?